I'm encountering an error with my POST API request: 'Error parsing JSON'
I'm new to SwiftUI and having trouble posting an API request, I have checked everything but still getting 500 server error message. I'm stuck on this please help if possible
Response data:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Server Error (500)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Server Error (500)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>


Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid
value around line 2, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid
value around line 2, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=1}

My code:
 do{

// Define the data to be sent
        let data: [String: String] = [
               "ad_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "device_id": "EE07C4CF-53CB-49D7-9991-111111111111",
               "device_token": "NOTFOUND"
           ]
    
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        // Convert the data dictionary to JSON data using JSONEncoder
        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(data)
        
     
        
        // Define the User-Agent header value
        let userAgentHeader = ["User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"]
        
        // Convert User-Agent header dictionary to JSON string
        guard let headerData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userAgentHeader, options: []),
              let headerJSON = String(data: headerData, encoding: .utf8) else {
            print("Failed to convert User-Agent header dictionary to JSON string")
            return
        }
                    
        // Create the request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // Define the headers dictionary
        let headers: [String: String] = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
        ]

        // Add the headers to the request
        for (key, value) in headers {
            request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
        
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        if let reqString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("paramater data: \(reqString)")
        }
        
        // Perform the request using URLSession
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // Handle the response
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            // Handle the data
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data received")
                return
            }
            
            // Print the data as a string to see what you received
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data: \(responseString)")
            }
            
            // Parse the response data
            do {
                // Try parsing the JSON with allowFragments option
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments])
                print("Response JSON: \(json)")
            } catch {
                print("Error parsing JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    } catch {
        // Handle the encoding error
        print("Error encoding data to JSON: \(error)")
    }


The response you get is clearly html and not json which explains the error so the question is more why you get that error response from the server. You have a variable headerData that you create but I can't see that you are using it, should it perhaps be added to headers?

I have fixed the issue now, still thank you for your suggestion. I was not passing the header in correct way and my server was expecting body in encrypted form.

My server was expecting encrypted data, that's why I was getting 500 server error. I have fixed the issue now and here's my code to post an api request:
func callGuestAPI() async {
    // Define the URL
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://your-base-url") else {
        return print("URL Error")
    }
    
    // Define the data to be sent
    let data: [String: String] = [
        "ad_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000022",
        "device_id": "EE07C4CF-53CB-49D7-9999-1AB613EEF222",
        "device_token": "NOTFOUND"
    ]
    
    //JSON Encoder
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    // Create the request
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    //Request Body
    guard let msgString = convertDictionaryToJSONString() else {
        return print("JSON Conversion error")
    }
    print("msgString \(msgString)") //not encrypted body
    
    // Encrypted Request body
    guard let jsonData: String = encrypt(msgString: msgString) else {
        return print("Encryption error")
    }
    print("jsonData \(jsonData)") //encrypted body
    
    // Define the headers dictionary
    let headers: [String: String] = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148",
    ]
    
    // Add the headers to the request
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    print("headers \(headers)")
    
    
    // Converting String body to Data
    guard let withoutEncryptedBody = msgString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return print("Invalid body")
    }
    request.httpBody = withoutEncryptedBody
    print("encryptedBody \(withoutEncryptedBody)")
    
    
    // Perform the request using URLSession
    do{
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("URLSession Received data:\n\(str ?? "")")
                
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    
    
}

